# how to use shared preferences in checkboxListTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

When I click on the checkbox, the tick is working; and I go back to the home screen and come to check again, the tick is disappeared, and the function is working on untick or unchecked.
So how to use shared preference in the checkbox? My main purpose is for a checkbox to work perfectly when a user clicks on it. When a user again clicks on it closes its functionality.

Comment: read about state management and shared prefferences

Comment: How does this question have anything to do with entity-framework or fluent-nhibernate?